# Transform options of SelectorRow

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

Is it possible to transform the options of a `MultipleSelectorRow`? I want to transform each option to `$0.capitalized`. I first tried `$0.displayValueFor` but it looks like that is for the value displayed in the form? Reading the issues, I was able to this:

```
.onPresent { _, to in
  to.sectionKeyForValue = { $0.capitalized }
}
```

Which will add sections. Is there any property that will allow me to map options to display values?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
<<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>() {
                $0.options = ["prueba","prueba","prueba3"]
                $0.tag = "gradeType"
                $0.title = "Grade Types"
                $0.selectorTitle = "Pick the posted grade types"
                //$0.value = prevGradeTypeList
                //$0.options = gradeTypePicker
            }.cellSetup({ (pushSelectorCell, row) in
                row.options = row.options.map({$0.capitalized})
            })
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: That still gives me the capitalized versions when I call `form.values()`. It is no different than setting the options to capitalized in the setup. I need a function that maps the options to **only** the displayed values and **not** the real values.

Answer (score 0):

This might also work:

```
.onPresent { _, to in
  to.selectableRowCellUpdate = { cell, row in
     if let title = row.selectableValue?.capitalized {
          cell.textLabel?.text = title
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the type you use for your options with `CustomStringConvertible` and override the `description` property.

```swift
public enum MySelectorType: String, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case one
    case two
    case three
    case four
    
    public var description: String {
        return rawValue.localizedCapitalized
    }
}
```

```swift
let myRow = MultipleSelectorRow<MySelectorType> { row in
    row.title = RLOC.edit_device_startup_on_off()
    row.options = MySelectorType.allCases
}
```